# Clean from .txt, write new variable as a csv delimited string (not list) into a csv file

Tags: python, csv

my .txt file looks like the following:

```
Page 1 of 49
<="">
View Full Profile
S.S. Anne
Oil Tanker
42 miles offshore
Anchor length is 50 feet
<="">
View Full Profile
S.S. Minnow
Passenger Ship
1502.2 miles offshore
Anchor length is 12 feet
<="">
View Full Profile
S.S. Virginia
Passenger Ship
2 km offshore
Anchor length is 25 feet
<="">
View Full Profile
S.S. Chesapeake
Naval Ship
10 miles offshore
Anchor length is 75 feet
<="">
```

I've worked out the cleaning part so that following 'View Full Profile' I take the next 4 line items and put them into their own new line item, I do this for each instance of 'View Full Profile'.

Code:

```
import csv 

data = []
with open('ship.txt','r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if 'View Full Profile' in line:
            x = [lines[i+1],lines[i+2],lines[i+3],lines[i+4]]
            data.append(x)

for line in data:
    y = line
    print(y)

with open('ship_test.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for line in data:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

And the output of printing y to see what will be written into the new file is:

```
['S.S. Anne\n', 'Oil Tanker\n', '42 miles offshore\n', 'Anchor length is 50 feet\n']
['S.S. Minnow\n', 'Passenger Ship\n', '1502.2 miles offshore\n', 'Anchor length is 12 feet\n']
['S.S. Virginia\n', 'Passenger Ship\n', '2 km offshore\n', 'Anchor length is 25 feet\n']
['S.S. Chesapeake\n', 'Naval Ship\n', '10 miles offshore\n', 'Anchor length is 75 feet\n']
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

When it copies into the new file I get the following:

```
"S.S. Anne
","Oil Tanker
","42 miles offshore
","Anchor length is 50 feet
"
"S.S. Minnow
","Passenger Ship
","1502.2 miles offshore
","Anchor length is 12 feet
"
"S.S. Virginia
","Passenger Ship
","2 km offshore
","Anchor length is 25 feet

"
"S.S. Chesapeake
","Naval Ship
","10 miles offshore
","Anchor length is 75 feet
"
```

I am looking to write into the new file the output of y. I believe it writes each item as its own line due to the '/n' attached to each element of x. How do I remove this (I tried splitting and received an error) so that x is written as a single line item in the new file as a csv string?

Answer (score 0):

```
line = line.replace('\n', '')
```

Use the replace method

If there is a list of strings:

```
line = [l.replace('\n', '') for l in line]
```

Comment: I've been trying replace and split dot notations, however get an error because line is a list.

    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: @JohnHanlon did you see the second part of my answer?

Comment: I added it in after the For loop and before the if 'View Full Profile' and the program run, however nothing was printed, seems like it just cleared out everything and didn't return / allow for the append to occur

Answer (score 0):

You should strip the terminating newline as soon as you read the line. The first part of your code could become:

```
data = []
with open('ship.txt','r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in lines:
        if 'View Full Profile' in line:
            x = [ next(f).strip(), next(f).strip(),
                  next(f).strip(), next(f).strip() ]
            data.append(x)
```

You could even write the csv file on the fly:

```
with open('ship.txt','r',encoding='utf8') as f, open('ship_test.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for line in f:
        if 'View Full Profile' in line:
            x = [ next(f).strip(), next(f).strip(),
                  next(f).strip(), next(f).strip() ]
            writer.writerow(x)
```

Comment: I received an erro when trying to run with the fopen - haven't found much material on it online either, am I missing something with the fopen?
NameError: name 'fopen' is not defined

Comment: It was of course a typo :-( . It is fixed now. Above code should run without error and without the need of loading everything in memory.